# How to obtain the separate parts of a string when you don't know the amount of parts there will be

Tags: python, string, split

I have searched and searched yet found nothing for my application

```
def getInput():
    command = input("What would you like to do now? ").split()
    verb_word = command[0]

    if verb_word in verbDict:   
        verb = verbDict[verb_word]
    else:      
        print('Unknown command: "{}"'.format(verb_word))
        print("The commands are:")        
        for i in len(verb_dict):
            print(verbDict[i])
```

I already have a split but I need the separate parts and then to call a function with them that has multiple parameters yet none are the same.

Comment: This question isn't particularly clear. What do you want the result to be?

Comment: @Metropolis I'm trying to call a function using the separate parts of a string
ie. spam(var1, var2, var3) or spam2(var4)

Comment: there's a trouble with formatting/indents

Comment: BTW: instead of `for i in len():` (or rather `for i in range(len()):`) you can use `for word in verb_dict: print(word)`

Comment: You could try using the argparse module, which is usually for command line arguments, but can take a string. Python website has a tutorial https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/argparse.html#id1 . Don't know whether you'd see that as. Overkill though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are accepting inputs that look something like

```
command parameter another_parameter
```

and you want to end up with something like

```
verb_dict['command']('parameter', 'another_parameter')
```

You can use python's packing and unpacking to do this

```
command, *parameters = input("What would you like to do now? ").split()
```

You then have `command = 'command'` and `parameters = ['parameter', 'another_parameter']`

You can then look up the function in the dictionary and then unpack the list into the function call

```
verb_dict['command'](*parameters)
```

Comment: This only works with Python 3 (for the `command, *parameters` unpacking part). For Python 2, you want `command, paramers = command[0], command[1:]`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I assumed from the usage of `input`, and the `print` function that this was python 3

Comment: we often see python beginners (mis)using `input()` (instead of `raw_input()` and adding parens to `print` while using python2 - either out of ignorance or because they saw this in python 3 tutorials ;-)